# Strange behavior of simple Python CGI script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi

For testing purposes, I created a very simple CGI script in Python 2.7, as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
version = sys.version.split('\n')[0]
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<html>"
print "<head><title>First Python HTTP Programming </title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello World!</h2>"
print "<h3>Python Version: </h3>" + version
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

In a local or remote host, it works just fine!

I then added just a few lines to this script, in order to check if one specific package is available:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
version = sys.version.split('\n')[0]
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print "<html>"
print "<head><title>First Python HTTP Programming </title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h3>Python Version: </h3>" + version
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    print "<h3> Already installed </h3>"
except ImportError as e:
    print "<h3>Not installed</h3>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

And then the script fails with a dreaded "Internal server failure" error!

I cannot see anything obviously wrong with such an ordinary piece of code. Could someone out there provide me with an explanation?

Please notice that I am using Python 2.7 because I have no privileged access to the server and that is the version they have available (but I do not believe the error is related to this or that version of Python).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the server's logs give you any details on what failure occurred?

Comment: Is it possible the permissions changed when you deployed the new copy of the script?  Can you try just running the script at the command line?

Comment: Chris: in the free hosting I am doing my tests I have no access to the server logs. Samwise: I checked the permissions and they are the same for both scripts; and yes, both also run fina at the command line.

Comment: Both does the job without error.

Comment: I have no access to the server log files, but just realized I can access the logs in the localhost! Here is the strange message I found: "malformed header from script 'check.py': Bad header: <html>". How the header of the second script is different from that of the first script is outside my understanding!